Is document.all a function or an object?
I know that typeof document.all returns "undefined", but if I am writing a set of functions to implement proper type check in JavaScript, what would the appropriate return value for it be? "object" or "function"?

the best answer is, it's a deprecated feature and should not be relied on

@JaromandaX Haha! That's not an answer. A word of advice: if someone asks about the nature of a thing, then, EVEN IF that thing is deprecated, you either provide an answer or don't say anything at all.

Though it's deprecated, it should be object. Why? Because it's (at least it seems to be) an array, try doing typeof []. You will see that it returns object.
